# Hybrid connection to on-premise BizTalk server

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, biztalk, biztalk-services

I have an ASP.NET web application running in Azure, with a Hybrid Connection to my server where BizTalk is installed. I can connect to the port 1433 to access the database.

But, my question: How can I connect to the BizTalk server resource (so I could use BizTalk.Operations.dll for example) instead of the SQL database? Do I just have to change the port of the Hybrid Connection, or should I install an ASP.NET application on the server and use the port of the on-premise web application in the Hybrid Connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is not the way you should use Hybrid Connections for this scenario. (take a look at the example scenarios [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/biztalk-services/integration-hybrid-connection-overview))
Yes, you can use Hybrid Connections to access an on-premise SQL Server (like the BizTalk Management database), but you should not try to use it with an interface like the BizTalk.Operations DLL.

The design you are trying to accomplish should have an "Operations Web API" on-premise, possibly best hosted on the BizTalk server or on a server that can access it.
This API can then be reached by your Azure resource using Hybrid Connections as this is a valid HC scenario. Also, using this design, you are not exposing all capabilities of the BizTalk.Operations DLL to the 'outside'.

*Possible Sample Architecture:*

```
                                                     +--------+
                                                     |  BTS 1 |
+--------+                       +-----------+       |        |
| Azure  |   +--------------+    |  On-Prem  +-------+--------+
| WebApp |---+  Azure  HC   +----+  WebApi   |
|        |   +--------------+    |           +-------+--------+
+--------+                       +-----------+       |        |
                                                     |  BTS 2 |
                                                     +--------+
```

Comment: Great, I was already thinking of doing it this way, but wasn't sure it would be a good idea as you need an extra client layer. Thanks!!